# Why does this enter an infinite loop?

Tags: excel, vba

Excel (2010) vba, this code enters an infinite loop (I assume because of the "Goto"...why?):

```
Sub KillEmptyRows()
Dim row As Range
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = ActiveSheet
Dim rowsdeleted As Integer
Dim i As Integer
rowsdeleted = 0
RerunRecursively:
        For i = 1 To sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            rowsdeleted = rowsdeleted + 1
            Set row = sheet.Rows(i)
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(row) = 0 Then
                row.Delete
            End If
        Next i
        If rowsdeleted > 0 Then
            rowsdeleted = 0
            GoTo RerunRecursively
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Because it checks on rowsdelete > 0 and the first thing you do in your loop is setting rowsdeleted + 1. So I assume that the defined range (UsedRange) is never cleared?

Comment: I'm an idiot. It should have incremented rowsdeleted right after the row.Delete statement. Sorry for the intrusion.... d'oh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is already mentioned in the comments, you are checking the below condition before calling the recursion

```
If rowsdeleted > 0
```

And when you enter in the loop you are setting the value to

```
rowsdeleted = rowsdeleted + 1
```

So the value is always true and hence an infinite loop

Comment: It was pretty tight, too!

Comment: @JimS-Indy:- Yes indeed!:)